# Переключение между экранами игры

Tags: python, tkinter

Я хочу создать главное меню игры. У меня есть два экрана - экран меню и экран игры. В главном меню у меня цикл `while True`, чтобы после перехода в экран игры можно было выйти и цикл бы создал опять главное меню.

Проблема заключается в том, что походу из-за `mainloop` нельзя вернуться в цикл `while True`. Значит `mainloop` нужно остановить, чтобы попасть снова в цикл и создалось меню? Как это сделать?

Или может вообще делать меню с помощью бесконечного цикла это плохая идея? Если это так, то как тогда это сделать?

Вот код:

```py
from tkinter import *

def back_to_main_menu():
    # Здесь надо как-то остановить mainloop
    ...

def game_screen():
    game_b = Button(root, text="Back to main menu", width=15, command=back_to_main_menu)
    game_b.pack(anchor=NW)
    game_l = Label(text="Game screen")
    game_l.pack()

def show_game_screen():
    menu_b1.destroy()

    game_screen()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x500")

while True:
    menu_b1 = Button(root, text="Play", width=15, command=show_game_screen)
    menu_b1.pack()
    
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужен бесконечный цикл. Просто в одной функции создаете меню, в другой - создаете экран игры, между экранами переключаетесь кнопками, как у вас и сделано. Перед пересозданием экрана окно очищаете.

```
from tkinter import *


def clear_window():
    # Удалить все объекты из окна
    for widget in root.slaves():
        widget.destroy()


def main_menu():
    clear_window()
    menu_b1 = Button(root, text="Play", width=15, command=game_screen)
    menu_b1.pack()


def game_screen():
    clear_window()
    game_b = Button(root, text="Back to main menu", width=15, command=main_menu)
    game_b.pack(anchor=NW)
    game_l = Label(text="Game screen")
    game_l.pack()


root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x500")

main_menu()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это все решает

Comment: В целом, ваш пример один из вариантов реализации меню. Меня только что осенило, что можно в моем примере в фунции `back_to_main_menu` добавить строчку `root.quit()`, благодаря которой можно как раз выйти из `mainloop`, ну и плюс можно добавить вашу функцию `clear()` - тогда как раз получится реализация меню с бесконечном циклом :D

Comment: @KirrP не нужен бесконечный цикл. Когда вы переходите от консольных программ к оконным, нужно перестать рассматривать программу как линейную последовательность действий, а думать состояниями приложения и переходами между ними. Вот два экрана у вас - это два состояния, вызов функции - это переход.

Comment: root.quit() - это как если бы вы не знали как закрыть программу на компе, и чтобы открыть другую программу полностью перезагружали компьютер

Comment: В целом ты прав. Бесконечный цикл я взял именно от консольных программ. В общем спасибо за ответы, буду иметь ввиду )

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать `root.destroy()`. Это должно будет остановить `mainloop`.

Comment: `root.destroy()`  уничтожает все виджеты и выходит из `mainloop`. В моем случае мне нужно только остановить `mainloop` и запустить его снова. Но все равно спасибо за ответ )